# Pointfree dynamic function composition

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, pointfree

I'm trying to refactor this function to be pointfree.

```
function siblings(me) {
  return R.pipe(family, R.reject(equalsMe(me)))(me);
}
```

I'd like to pass `me` to a function down the pipe along with the value that `family` returns.

Tried a few things with `R.useWith` or `R.converge` with `R.identity` or `R.__` (not even sure if I should be using that) but found nothing to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly `family` is a function that takes a person and returns a list of family members (including that person) e.g.

```js
family(2);
//=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Then you want to create a function `siblings` which takes a person and returns only their siblings e.g.

```js
siblings(2);
//=> [1, 3]
```

Personally I think your function would read slightly better if it was written this way:

```js
const siblings = me => reject(equals(me), family(me));

siblings(2);
//=> [1, 3]
```

If you *really* wanted a pointfree version of it, you *could* use `converge` but I really don't think it is any better:

```js
const siblings = converge(reject, [unary(equals), family]);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was struggling to understand `unary` and `converge` but I think I do now!

Comment: I like your version with the single `me` parameter.  But for point-free, I would prefer `lift` to `converge` wherever it will work, as it does here.  So `const siblings = lift (reject) (unary (equals), family)`.  If this didn't need `unary`, I'd actually be pretty happy with it.

Answer (score 7):

I'd also suggest using `R.converge` and swapping `R.reject(equalsMe(me))` with `R.without(me)`

```js
const withFamily = R.always(['fratello', 'sorella', 'io']);

const siblingsOf = R.converge(R.without, [
  R.identity,
  withFamily,
]);

console.log(
  siblingsOf('io'),
);

console.log(
  siblingsOf('sorella'),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I always forget about `without`; nice one.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using R.without (as suggested in [Hitmands answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67224993/5157454)), you can use R.chain with a flipped R.without:

```
chain(flip(without), withFamily);
```

Because `chain(f, g)(x)` is equivalent to `f(g(x), x)`:

```
chain(flip(without), withFamily)(me)
```

equals to:

```
flippedWithout(withFamily(me), me)
```

Example:

```js
const { always, chain, flip, without } = R;

const withFamily = always(['fratello', 'sorella', 'io']);

const siblingsOf = chain(flip(without), withFamily);

console.log(
  siblingsOf('io'),
);

console.log(
  siblingsOf('sorella'),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I knew `chain` could have been used here but couldn't figure out how. Nice.

Comment: Same here. The R without was the missing link in the chain.